# psql '\copy' can't use bash variable?

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, sh, psql

I have a bash script which read into a text file and launch a psql command for each line into this file.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat textfile.txt | while read line
do
  echo "id=$line started"
  psql -U username -h host -p port -d database -f copyUpdateData.sql -v line="$line"
  echo "id $line done"
done
```

My copyDataUpdate.sql looks like :

```
\copy (select data from "SCHEMA"."TABLE" where id = :line ) To 'test.txt';
update "SCHEMA"."TABLE" set status='done' where id = :line;
```

The update command works just fine, however I get a syntax error for the \copy command.

> psql:copyUpdateData.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
>
> LINE 1: ...Y  ( select data from "SCHEMA" . "TABLE" where id = :line ) TO...

I tried to replace the variable with a value and it worked.

Is there a way to use my variable into my \copy command ?

And would it be also possible to add it into the destination filename ? I tried something like `'test_' || :line || '.txt'` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Edit : I've been redirected to another topic but I believe that the answer is what I am already doing.

Does my syntax seem correct ? Because I can't see where the error could be.

Comment: `"SCHEME" . "TABLE"` seems different than `"SCHEMA" . "TABLE"`

Comment: oh yeah that was a typo sorry when I wrote the question I changed manually the names